# Trip advisor Axesso Api

Tags: php, api, rest

I am working with Trip advisor Axesso Api , I want to format my response to json formatted format ,
this is the code I have used

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, [
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://axesso-expedia-data-service.p.rapidapi.com/exp/expedia-lookup-reviews?page=2&propertyId=xxxxxx",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
        "x-rapidapi-host: axesso-expedia-data-service.p.rapidapi.com",
        "x-rapidapi-key: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxe"
    ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
    echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
    echo '<pre>';
    echo $response;
    echo '<pre>';
}
```

I have tried also

```
$response = json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

But none of them has worked,
Do anyone has an idea about this problem,
Thanks in advance

Comment: What response do you get on this one?

Comment: I got JSON response but not formatted

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a PHP expert but here to help. I believe this should work:

```
$array = json_decode($response, true);
```